# Loop Scraping in R with rvest - Football Stats

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to get R to loop through player profiles on transfermarket.com, I first grab the roster URLs with the following.

```
#/ Add the Team’s URL to scrape

TeamScrape <- read_html("http://www.transfermarkt.com/jumplist/startseite/verein/2778")


#// Get Club Name

ClubName <- TeamScrape %>%
html_nodes(".spielername-profil") %>%
html_text()

#// Get All Player URLs 

PlayerURLs <- TeamScrape %>%
html_nodes(".spielprofil_tooltip") %>%
html_attr("href")

PlayerURLs <- unique(PlayerURLs)
PlayerURLs <- na.omit(PlayerURLs)

PlayerURLs <- paste0("http://www.transfermarkt.com", PlayerURLs)

PlayerLinks = data.frame(ClubName, PlayerURLs)
```

This gives me a data.frame including the URLs that I want to loop through my next scraper - the 'Player Profile Scraper'.

```
#/ Add the Player’s URL that you want to scrape
URLLink <- PlayerURLs[13]
PlayerTest <- read_html(URLLink)


#// Squad No 

SquadNo <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes(".rueckennummer-profil") %>%
html_text()


#// Name 

Name <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes(".spielername-profil") %>%
html_text() 

#// Nationality 

Nationality <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes(".flaggenrahmen+ span") %>%
html_text() 

#// Club 

Club <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes(".vereinprofil_tooltip+ .vereinprofil_tooltip") %>%
html_text() 

#// Position 

Position <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes(".list+ .list tr:nth-child(3) td") %>%
html_text()

#// DOB

DOB <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes(".wsnw") %>%
html_text()

#// Age 

Age <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes(".profilheader .hide-for-small td") %>%
html_text() %>%
as.numeric()

#// Value 

Value <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes(".marktwert a") %>%
html_text()

#// Matches Played this Season

Matches <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes(".hide.hide-for-small+ .zentriert") %>%
html_text() %>%
as.numeric()

#// Goals Scored this Season

Goals <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes("#yw1 tfoot .zentriert:nth-child(4)") %>%
html_text() %>%
as.numeric()

#// Assists Made this Season

Assists <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes("tfoot .zentriert:nth-child(5)") %>%
html_text() %>%
as.numeric()

#// Mins Played this Season

Minutes <- PlayerTest %>%
html_nodes("tfoot .zentriert:nth-child(7)") %>%
html_text() %>%
as.numeric()

#// Some Cleaning Up of the Data 

# to_remove_SquadNo <- paste(c("#"))
# SquadNo <- gsub(to_remove_SquadNo, "", SquadNo)

# Minutes <- regmatches(Minutes, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", Minutes))
# as.numeric(unlist(Minutes))

#// Create the Data Frame 

output = data.frame(SquadNo, Name, Nationality, Club, Position, DOB, Age, Value, Matches, Goals, Assists, Minutes)
```

My aim is to loop the player profile scraper based on the URLs that come out of the Team Scraper. I have tried numerous different loop attempts and I am lost! Would really appreciate some advice!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
URLLink <- PlayerURLs[13]
```

by

```
lapply(PlayerURLs, FUN=function(URLLink){
```

and add at the end

```
output
})
```

Comment: HubertL - thanks for the quick response. I did as you stated and I got this: Error in data.frame(SquadNo, Name, Nationality, Club, ContractUntil, Position,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In function_list[[k]](value) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In function_list[[k]](value) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In function_list[[k]](value) : NAs introduced by coercion
Called from: data.frame(SquadNo, Name, Nationality, Club, ContractUntil, Position, 
    DOB, Age)

Comment: It's because some data is missing

Comment: Strange, even if I reduce the scrapping down to 2 factors it says I have differing in rows values...

Comment: I solved this issue by using `rep()` on the fixed fields, which only appear once in the standard output and based the number of repetitions on the length of the longest data item.
If still necessary I can provide a full answer.